# Why must the caret character ^ escaped on running a search/find/replace in UltraEdit?

Tags: ultraedit

When I am trying to search for some word containing caret character `^` in UltraEdit, it is not showing me any searched result. For this I have to search the word with double occurrence of `^^`.

Example:

The string to find is `Search^This`. But I have to search with `Search^^This`.

Is there any solution so that I don't have to put two `^` characters in search popup text area because some of the variable names in program may contain more than 2 or even more `^` characters.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that `^` has a special meaning in UE's search strings (more details in help). To search for `^` you have to enter `^^`.

Answer (score 1):

In **Find** or **Replace** window (not docked), press key F1 to open help page, or click on button **Help** (older versions of UltraEdit) in the dialog, or take a look on online help page about [Find command](http://www.ultraedit.com/help/article/find-command-1324.html) for an explanation why `^` must be escaped with an additional `^` to be interpreted as literal character.

The options you have:

1. On a **non** regular expression Find/Replace you have to escape each `^` by inserting an additional `^`.
2. On an **UltraEdit** regular expression Find/Replace you have to escape each `^` by inserting an additional `^` or alternatively use `?` for each `^` to match any character except carriage return or line-feed.
3. Using **Unix** or **Perl** regular expression Find/Replace is also of no real help as `^` means beginning of line. So even on a **Unix/Perl** regular expression Find/Replace you have to escape each `^` by inserting before the escape character `\` resulting in `\^` to get character `^` interpreted as literal character. Or alternatively you use `.` for each `^` to match any character except new line characters.
4. For **non/UltraEdit** regular expression Finds/Replaces it would be possible at **Advanced - Configuration - Search - Miscellaneous** to define a different character than `^` as *Special character used in find/replace strings*. You can use this setting and define for example `\` or `#` as escape character. But make use of that option just for doing the Finds/Replaces on the strings with `^` in file and then change the configuration setting back to `^` as otherwise you will encounter definitely problems in future. Everything written about using UltraEdit or non regular expression Finds/Replaces assumes that `^` is the escape character.

Comment: Hehe, that why I made this remark about "short answer" - I knew you'd respond too ;-)